# Updating graphics on an interval

Tags: java, graphics, updates

What's the best way to update a screen every interval of time *t* for graphics?  Assuming the update method is called with `update()`, and all actual graphics stuff takes place there and is already handled and everything.

I've used the javax.swing.Timer which triggers an action event ever specified interval of time to run my update methods in the past, however the speed of the computer is still a factor.  So if I'm doing it the best way (which I doubt) how do I leave updating exclusive to time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system clock calls in Java aren't necessarily super accurate.  Here's one way to take into account update time when waiting for a specified period.

In this example, we're updating every 40 milliseconds, or 25 frames a second.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class TimerRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static final long interval = 40L; // 40 milliseconds

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            update();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
            elapsedTime = Math.max((interval - elapsedTime), 5L);
            sleep(elapsedTime);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    private void sleep(long interval) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    private void update() {

    }

}
```

We see how long it takes to perform the update method.  We calculate the elapsed time, and make sure the interval minus the elapsed time doesn't fall below 5 milliseconds.  if it takes longer than 35 milliseconds to do the update, we will drop the frame rate to keep up.

Comment: To clarify, would a class like the javax.swing.Timer still follow sequential execution rather than threading the actionPerformed? And if so, what are the takebacks of threading an update method rather than what you've suggested?

Comment: @Jared Massa: I've never used a javax.swing.Timer, so someone else will have to answer your questions.  I use Runnable classes for my animations.